# Поменять первую и последнюю букву каждого слова

Tags: c#

Как это все объединить? Не могу понять , как это все объединить .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApp9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string stroka = Console.ReadLine();
            stroka.Split();
            stroka.PadRight(1);

            string[] convert = stroka.Split();

            foreach (string stroka2 in convert)
            {
                StringBuilder stroka0 = new StringBuilder(stroka2);
                StringBuilder stroka1 = new StringBuilder(stroka2);

                stroka0.Replace(stroka0[0], stroka0[stroka0.Length - 1]);
                stroka1.Replace(stroka1[stroka1.Length - 1], stroka1[0]);
                Console.Write(stroka0);
                Console.Write(stroka1);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static string SwapFirstAndLastChars(string inputString)
{
    if(inputString == null || inputString.Length < 2)
    {
        return inputString;
    }

    char[] chars = inputString.ToCharArray();
    chars[0] = inputString[inputString.Length-1];
    chars[inputString.Length-1] = inputString[0];
    return new string(chars);
}
```

https://ideone.com/m3iXW7

Comment: Либо проще: `(chars[0], chars[^1]) = (chars[^1], chars[0]);`, только не помню с какой версии языка такое работает.